# GL_COLOR_MATERIAL with lighting on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

It appears that [`glColorMaterial()`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glColorMaterial.3G.html) is absent from [OpenGL ES](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/). According to [this post](http://www.idevgames.com/forum/showthread.php?t=18189) (for iPhone), you may still enable `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` in OpenGL ES 1.x, but you're stuck with the default settings of `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` and `GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE` that you would otherwise set with `glColorMaterial()`.  I would be OK with this, but the diffuse lighting is not working correctly.

I set up my scene and tested it with one light, setting `glMaterialfv()` for `GL_AMBIENT` and `GL_DIFFUSE` once in the initialization. The normals have been set correctly, and lighting works the way it's supposed to. I see the Gouraud shading.

With `GL_LIGHTING` disabled, the flat colors I have set with `glColor4f()` appear on the various objects in the scene. This also functions as expected.  However, when `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)` is called, the flat colors remain.  I would expect to see the lighting effects.

glColorMaterial() is also [mentioned on anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=33992), but I'm not sure if the information there is accurate.

I'm testing this on an Android 2.1 handset (Motorola Droid).

**Edit**: It works properly on my 1.6 handset (ADP1). I've filed [Issue 8015](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8015).
It does **not** work with the emulator for Android 1.6 or 2.1.

Here is a [minimal testcase](http://sites.google.com/site/droidful/bugs/color_material_testcase.zip) to reproduce the problem.

**Screenshot on Android 1.6 (ADP1):**

[image]

**Screenshot of same code running on Android 2.1 (Motorola Droid):**

[image]

**Screenshot on Android 1.6 (Emulator):**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a silly mistake on my part.  Given a 32-bit integer Android `color`, I had forgotten to scale the color components to floats in the range [0, 1]:

```
    gl.glColor4f(Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color), Color.alpha(color));
```

It should have bee like this:

```
    gl.glColor4f(Color.red(color)/(float) 0xFF, Color.green(color)/(float) 0xFF, Color.blue(color)/(float) 0xFF, Color.alpha(color)/(float) 0xFF);
```

I'm not sure why the first way still worked on my G1.